# Why does RegSetValueEx work even when I break the rule about accounting for NUL termination in the length?

Tags: c++, c, string, winapi, registry

I've got a simple program that adds calc.exe to startup:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int main(){
    _tprintf(TEXT("Adding calc.exe to SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run...\n"));

    HKEY hRegRunKey;
    LPCTSTR lpKeyName = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");
    LPCTSTR lpKeyValue = TEXT("Calculator");

    LPCTSTR lpProgram = TEXT("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\calc.exe");
    DWORD cchProgram = _tcslen(lpProgram);

    _tprintf(TEXT("Path: %s. \n"), lpProgram);
    _tprintf(TEXT("Length: %d. \n"), cchProgram);

    if(RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, lpKeyName, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &hRegRunKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS){
        if(RegSetValueEx(hRegRunKey, lpKeyValue, 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE *)lpProgram, cchProgram * sizeof(TCHAR)) != ERROR_SUCCESS){
            _tprintf(TEXT("ERROR: Can't set key value.\n"));
            exit(1);
        }else{
            _tprintf(TEXT("Key has been added sucessfully.\n"));
        }
    }

    Sleep(5000);
    RegCloseKey(hRegRunKey);
}
```

For me the world of c/c++/WIN32API is still full of misteries... so I have few questions.

**1. When I define string is it automatically null terminated?**

```
LPCTSTR lpProgram = TEXT("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\calc.exe");
```

or should it be done:

```
LPCTSTR lpProgram = TEXT("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\calc.exe\0");
```

**2. In my code is final argument to RegSetValueEx set to correct value?**

From [MSDN - RegSetValueEx function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page:

> cbData [in] The size of the information pointed to by the lpData
>   parameter, in bytes. If the data is of type REG_SZ, REG_EXPAND_SZ, or
>   REG_MULTI_SZ, cbData must include the size of the terminating null
>   character or characters.

**cchProgram** is set to 28 characters **without** null termination. On my system(because of UNICODE I think?) **cchProgram * sizeof(TCHAR)** = 56.

Shouldn't I set it to 58 to add null termination?

---

When I run this program, as it is above, without any modifications and I'll check Calculator value in registry via **Modify binary date** I get:

```
43 00 3A 00 5C 00 57 00 C.:.\.W.
49 00 4E 00 44 00 4F 00 I.N.D.O.
57 00 53 00 5C 00 73 00 W.S.\.s.
79 00 73 00 74 00 65 00 y.s.t.e.
6D 00 33 00 32 00 5C 00 m.3.2.\.
63 00 61 00 6C 00 63 00 c.a.l.c.
2E 00 65 00 78 00 65 00 ..e.x.e.
00 00                   ..
```

Its 58 bytes including null termination. I'am confuse:/

**UPDATE**

Accounting for a NULL character by adding 1 to string length when calculating **cbData** yields exactly same result as without adding it.

> **cchProgram * sizeof(TCHAR)** produces same data entry as **(cchProgram + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR)**

Providing value smaller then a string length doesn't add NULL byte and copies given number of bytes.

> **27 * sizeof(TCHAR)** as cbData produces:

```
43 00 3A 00 5C 00 57 00 C.:.\.W.
49 00 4E 00 44 00 4F 00 I.N.D.O.
57 00 53 00 5C 00 73 00 W.S.\.s.
79 00 73 00 74 00 65 00 y.s.t.e.
6D 00 33 00 32 00 5C 00 m.3.2.\.
63 00 61 00 6C 00 63 00 c.a.l.c.
2E 00 65 00 78 00       ..e.x.
```

I am on some old XP, service pack god knows what, I don't know how other version of windows would handle it.

Comment: App of the information you provided in your subject should be tags, which means that you've posted no subject information here. Please [edit] your question and do so. Tag information belongs in the tags; the tagging system here is very good and doesn't need any help. Thanks.

Comment: @Ken White could you help me with that please? I cant find better title then this. I think that stack overflow has option for people to edit other people posts. Change it for more accurate title and I will definitely accept it.

Comment: @Kocur4d: Made your title into an on-topic summary, I hope that suits you.

Comment: @Kocur4d: Ben beat me to it. :-) Your title needs to describe your question topic (the information that doesn't fit in the tags, and provides information about what you're asking). The tags classify the question into general subjects (in this case, `winapi`, `c++`) so that people who are familiar with those subjects see them, and so they can be properly found in searches by future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I define string is it automatically null terminated?

String literals are null-terminated, yes. `"Hello"` is actually `{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}`.

> In my code is final argument to RegSetValueEx set to correct value?

You're right that you need the null terminator. An easier way would be `sizeof(TEXT("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\calc.exe"))` if the string literal is short, since `sizeof("Hello")` is 6; it includes the null-terminator, but in most cases, you'll need your variable and will have to add one to the length you get from string character-counting functions, since they don't include the null-terminator.

Ben Voigt made an excellent point below that a `const TCHAR[] program = TEXT("text");` can be used the same way as a literal in the call (`sizeof(program)`), but it a lot more maintainable when you want to change one less place in the code, which is a must for any actual project instead of a really small test, and even that can grow.

Finally, there are two things you should get out of your head early:

1. Hungarian notation: Don't do it. It's outdated and rather pointless.
2. `TCHAR`: Just use wide strings with any Windows API functions you can.

What you're doing absolutely right is checking function calls for errors. You wouldn't believe how many problems asked about can be solved by checking for failure and using `GetLastError` when the documentation says to.

---

Since you asked how you're supposed to use C++ facilities, here's one way, with a couple changes that make more sense for using C++:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
    //R means raw string literal. Note one backslash
    std::cout << R"(Adding calc.exe to SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run...)" << '\n';

    const WCHAR[] keyName = LR"(SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run)");

    std::cout << "Enter program name: ";
    std::wstring keyValue;        
    if (!std::getline(std::wcin, keyValue)) {/*error*/}

    std::cout << "Enter full program path: ";
    std::wstring program;
    if (!std::getline(std::wcin, program)) {/*error*/}

    std::wcout << "Path: " << program << ".\n";
    std::cout << "Length: " << program.size() << ".\n";

    HKEY runKey;
    if(RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, keyName, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &runKey)) {/*error*/}

    if(RegSetValueExW(runKey, keyValue.c_str(), 0, REG_SZ, reinterpret_cast<const BYTE *>(program.c_str()), (program.size() + 1) * 2)) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Can't set key value.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (RegCloseKey(runKey)) {/*error*/}

    std::cout << "Key has been added successfully.\n";

    std::cout << "Press enter to continue..."    
    std::cin.get();
}
```

A better way to do this using C++ idioms would be to at least have a `RegKey` RAII class that calls `RegCloseKey` in its destructor and saves you the work. At the very least, it could be used like this:

```
RegKey key(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, keyName, KEY_SET_VALUE);
RegSetValueExW(key, ...); //could have implicit or explicit conversion, fill in the ...
//RegCloseKey called when key goes out of scope
```

Comment: The `cch` prefix is very useful, actually, since it instantly tells someone reading the program that it is the number of characters, not the number of bytes.  The other prefixes I see in this code are quite useless.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I would personally use something like `prgmLen`. Honestly, I'd probably be using `std::wstring` and its `size()` function in place of storing it as a variable.

Comment: And `prgmLen` wouldn't tell me the important thing -- is it bytes or characters.  `cch` is GOOD Hungarian (aka Apps Hungarian).  `lp` is BAD Hungarian (aka System Hungarian).

Comment: @BenVoigt, Okay, characters vs bytes definitely. My mind uses a default of no indication to mean characters, but that definitely isn't apparent to everyone else.

Comment: Same complaint as with Steve: `lpProgram` is not a string literal. It is a pointer to a string literal. And `sizeof lpProgram` is the size of a pointer, not the length of the string.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I just realized that when you commented on the other answer. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Repeating string literals inside `sizeof` is not really a good recommendation either.

Comment: Besides that, you've multiplied by `sizeof (TCHAR)` twice, which is also wrong.

Comment: @BenVoigt, True, it might be good in limited situations, like small test programs, which is why I said "in most cases". It doesn't scale well at all, especially if you use the string in more than one place. A constant of some sort is a lot easier to change.

Comment: One could write `TCHAR tszProgram[] = { TEXT("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\calc.exe") };` and then `sizeof (tszProgram)` would be the length, in bytes, including the NUL terminator.

Comment: @BenVoigt, Geez, I'm really having a bad time with little errors that make a big difference today. That array is definitely better, and sort of the same as a `std::basic_string`, though the latter hates `TCHAR`s depending on how you use it (for example, no `tstoi`). `std::wstring` is really often a lot easier to work with over the course of the program if changes need to be made, but a constant array works well for just replacing the text.

Comment: can you expand a bit on not using Hungarian and TCHAR please? Maybe a link to more up-to-date resources(programming guidance, etc...)? I am using some online one that spread from 1995 till now. You also mention about std::*** approach, would it be a problem for you to rewrite this program using std(C++) and share a gist with me? Just so I can see other ways to achieve same thing. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Kocur4d, Do you mean Petzold's book? By all means, use it. It's arguably the best Windows API learning resource. However, Hungarian notation has gotten pretty out of date since then. If you need to check the type of something, you can mouse over it. `lp` is more just `p` now, since near and far pointers are obsolete. You'll have to use the Hungarian-named types when using the API, but it just adds bloat to your variable names. As for using a C++ approach, I'll see about that.

Comment: @Kocur4d, `TCHAR` is also getting out of date as well. If you pass a narrow string to any more modern version of Windows (I believe it was more from the DOS days when this wasn't true), it internally converts it to a wide string, processes that, and any result is converted to a narrow string for you. You can save it a lot of work by just using wide strings. It saves you a lot of work when not using `TCHAR` as well. Just prefix L on literals being used with the API, use the *W forms of functions (or `#define UNICODE`), and use `std::wcout` and other wide versions to deal with them.

Answer (score 3):

1: Yes, it will be null terminated without the need for `\0`.

> Double quoted strings (") are literal constants whose type is in fact a null-terminated array of characters. So string literals enclosed between double quotes always have a null character ('\0') automatically appended at the end.

2: `_tcslen()` doesn't include the null terminator.  You can add `sizeof(TCHAR)` to add it.

The reason the value still works is probably because Windows tries to be robust even when given incorrect input.  It is probably automatically appending the null terminator for you.  However, because the documentation says you must include the null terminator it may not always append it.

Comment: `lpProgram` is not a string literal.  It is a pointer to a string literal.  And `sizeof lpProgram` is the size of a pointer.  -1

Comment: The point about Windows being robust is a sad reality. If you read The Old New Thing, it's horrific seeing all of the dead code needed to maintain peace with broken applications.

Comment: I agree, it must be a real pain trying to maintain backwards compatibility.  I'd particularly hate to work in the AppCompat part of MS.